# Gdal Python documentation

Tags: gdal

Where Can I find the python documentation for gdal, I am getting file not found error opening the gdal documentations all the time  I have tried the following links

https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html

https://gdal.org/python/

Comment: I noticed this too. It was up just a few days ago. I hope it comes back online soon.

Answer (score 4):

How about the links that appear in the menu item "Python API" when you go to https://gdal.org?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately those docs are incomplete. For example, the gdalconst module page is blank.

Comment: I have tried that, but there  is not much information as you said.

Comment: Nothing better exists at the moment. As mentioned at https://gdal.org/api/python_bindings.html `The GDAL project (primarily Even Rouault) maintains SWIG generated Python bindings for GDAL and OGR. Generally speaking the classes and methods mostly match those of the GDAL and OGR C++ classes. There is no Python specific reference documentation`. However, that will improve soon, see https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pulls.